# Javascript reduce() on array of objects, with entries being simple variables and array as well

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I'm trying to use the reduce function in order to iterate through an array of objects and to get an output summing up the data shown inside of the array of objects (a kind of duplicate remover in fact).

On data such as :

```
mainData = [
   {data : {name: "item1", color: "red", type: ["metal", "wood"]}, id: 1},
   {data : {name: "item2", color: "green", type: ["wood"]}, id: 2},
   {data : {name: "item3", color: "green", type: ["wood", "stone", "marble"]}, id: 3},
   {data : {name: "item4", color: "red", type: ["stone"]}, id: 4}
]
```

when using the function :

```
const getValues = (data, key) => {
    return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
        if(acc.indexOf(item.data[key]) > -1) {
            return [...acc]
        } else {
            return [...acc, item.data[key]]
        }
    }, [data[0].data[key]]) //initial value
}
```

It will fork fine if I call this `getValues` function `getValues(mainData, "color")` for the `color` key,
giving the following output : `["red", "green"]`, which is expected.

But if i call the function with `getValues(mainData, "type")`, this function will ignore most of the values from the array type value from the key `type`.

I tried to solve it by using a `for` loop limited by `data["type"].length` just before the `if...else` condition of the reduce function, like this :

```
const getValues = (data, key) => {
    return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < item.data[key].length; i++) {
            if(acc.indexOf(item.data[key][i]) > -1) {
                return [...acc]
            } else {
                return [...acc, item.data[key][i]]
            }
        }
    }, [data[0].data[key][0]])
}
```

But it does not work either.

Anyone has an idea of how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `flatMap` for that

like this

```js
const mainData = [
   {data : {name: "item1", color: "red", type: ["metal", "wood"]}, id: 1},
   {data : {name: "item2", color: "green", type: ["wood"]}, id: 2},
   {data : {name: "item3", color: "green", type: ["wood", "stone", "marble"]}, id: 3},
   {data : {name: "item4", color: "red", type: ["stone"]}, id: 4}
]

const getValue = (data, key) => [...new Set(data.flatMap(({data}) => Array.isArray(data[key])?data[key]: [data[key]]))]

console.log(getValue(mainData, 'name'))
console.log(getValue(mainData, 'type'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It maybe easier to use [a Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to dedupe the values.

```js
const mainData=[{data:{name:"item1",color:"red",type:["metal","wood"]},id:1},{data:{name:"item2",color:"green",type:["wood"]},id:2},{data:{name:"item3",color:"green",type:["wood","stone","marble"]},id:3},{data:{name:"item4",color:"red",type:["stone"]},id:4}];

// Pass in the data, and the prop you want to look at
function finder(arr, prop) {

  // Create a new set
  const set = new Set();
  
  // Iterate over the array of objects
  for (const obj of arr) {

    const value = obj.data[prop];

    // If `value` is an array add each value to the set
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach(v => set.add(v));
    } else {

      // Otherwise just add the value
      set.add(obj.data[prop]);
    }
  }

  // Return an array from the set
  return [...set];

}

console.log(finder(mainData, 'color'));
console.log(finder(mainData, 'type'));
console.log(finder(mainData, 'name'));
```

Comment: hi @Andy, thank you for this solution. Unlike @R4ncid and @zer00ne , you're not using `flatMap` function, is it because of browser compatibility ?

Comment: No. I just thought a simple loop was a little more elegant. (I also don't one-liners).

Answer (score 1):

- `.flatMap()` the first layer searching for `keyA` ("data"). Each `data:{...}` object is converted into an array of pairs:

  ```js
  [["name","item1"],["color","red"],["type",["metal","wood"]],...];
  ```
- Another `.flatMap()` iterates through the array of pairs and returns a value when it gets a match with `keyB`. Everything else is returned as an empty array that will result in nothing since `.flatMap()` flattens it's returns.

  ```js
  ([k, v]) => k === keyB ? v :[])
  ```
- Finally, the return of both `flatMap()`s are made into a `Set()` then the `Set` is returned as an array sans duplicates.

  ```js
  return [...new Set(output)];
  ```

```js
const mainData = [
   {data : {name: "item1", color: "red", type: ["metal", "wood"]}, id: 1},
   {data : {name: "item2", color: "green", type: ["wood"]}, id: 2},
   {data : {name: "item3", color: "green", type: ["wood", "stone", "marble"]}, id: 3},
   {data : {name: "item4", color: "red", type: ["stone"]}, id: 4}
];

function compact(objArray, keyA, keyB) {
  const output = objArray.flatMap(
    obj => Object.entries(obj[keyA]).flatMap(
      ([k, v]) => k === keyB ? v :[]
    )
  );
  return [...new Set(output)];
}
console.log(compact(mainData, 'data', 'type'));
console.log(compact(mainData, 'data', 'color'));
console.log(compact(mainData, 'data', 'name'));
```

Comment: Hi @zer00ne , thank you for this solution, it works perfectly, and is quite intelligible